# org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireUpperBoundDeps failed with message:

Tags: java, maven

When I run "mvn clean install " I got those errors, what's the correct way to fix this issue? i tried to change the version of junit-jupiter to 5.7.0 but it cause more errors, can anyone help me with that?

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireUpperBoundDeps failed with message:
Failed while enforcing RequireUpperBoundDeps. The error(s) are [
Require upper bound dependencies error for org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 paths to dependency are:
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2
and
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2
and
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.1
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 (managed) <-- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0
and
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.1
    +-org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.6.28
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 (managed) <-- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2
and
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.1
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.0
        +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 (managed) <-- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0
,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule seems to enforce a [common upper bounds for a set of dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html): this may be used to achieve binary compatibility (eg: to ensure that you don't use a lower version that would be incompatible with a transitive dependency you use because its version would be greater).

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireUpperBoundDeps failed with message:
Failed while enforcing RequireUpperBoundDeps. The error(s) are [
Require upper bound dependencies error for org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 paths to dependency are:
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2
and
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2
and
+-my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.1
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 (managed) <-- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0
```

spring boot is importing junit at version 5.7.0, but you have specified junit 5.5.2.

Try to use the highest version (eg: 5.7.0).

Answer (score 1):

Maven determines the artifact versions with **nearest definition** rule. ​That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins.

Example : Shallowest one wins.

```
Your project dependencies
 ​+-A
   ​+-B
     ​+-C
       ​+-D-2.0
 ​+-E
   ​+-D-1.0    <- This version is used for artifact D as this is "nearest".
```

**Solution** : **update the version in the pom.xml to the newest version listed in the output** i.e. **5.7.0** in your case.

You can print the dependency tree `mvn dependency:tree` and see where you are getting the conflicts in actual.